# while using responce.css in scrapy it shows error invalid syntax

Tags: python, css, scrapy, web-crawler, spyder

Here is my code

```
import scrapy

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
name= 'Wikiipedia'
start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(electricity)']

def parsed(self, response):
    print response.css("h1#firstHeading::text").extract()
```

When executed in command prompt it shows the following error

```
print response.css("h1#firstHeading::text").extract()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what i did wrong.
Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: if you are using `python 3`, you need to add `parentheses` when you use `print`. `print(response.css("h1#firstHeading::text").extract())`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your codes it worked fine. (i think it should be 'parse' but not 'parsed')

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out that [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8150371/stack) was correct in my case. Python 3 requires you to use parentheses with the print statement and everything works fine then.